# Property does not exist on type Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I've tried to make a pretty basic class and for some reason I can't figure out why this variable "doesn't exist"

```
export class AppModule {
  public static currentHost: string = 'http://localhost:8080/';

  constructor() {
    if (window.location.hostname == "localhost") {
      this.currentHost = "http://" + window.location.hostname + "/";
    }
  }

}
```

`ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(62,12): error TS2339: Property 'currentHost' does not exist on type 'AppModule'.`

Anyone see my error?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the static keyword. Just do it like this

```
public  currentHost = 'http://localhost:8080/';
```

The `string` type is implied on the value you declared.

Comment: What if I want the variable to be static? Will it still behave like a static variable? Kinda like a global variable.

Comment: Why do you need it as a static? You probably came from a C#/Java background like me, check this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212521/typescript-static-classes.

Comment: If you want it to be static, call it as `AppModule.currentHost` instead.

Comment: Or create a separate file and save your constants there something like 
`export const myConfig = {
     serverUrl : ' http://localhost:8080/`
}
And you can use it in your component like this `this.currentHost = myConfig.serverUrl`

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't declare variables inside a module ,it should be inside a component which you want to use.