# how to create custom datatype in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have a object like below

```
export const appErrorTemplate = {
    NO_APP : {
        template : 'Unable to initialize #{0}()!',
        code : 'no-app'
    },
    NO_REQ_FOUND : {
        template : '#{0}() requires \'#{1}\' to process!',
        code : 'no-required-found'
    },
    MISMATH : {
        template : '#{0}() required #{1} but \'#{2}\' found!',
        code : 'mismatch'
    },
    NOT_SATISFY : {
        template : 'Given parameter on #{0}() does not satisfied #{1} constrains',
        code : 'not-satisfy'
    },
    UNKNOWN : {
        template : 'Something went wrong!',
        code : 'unknown'
    }
};
```

How to define datatype like object which has array of object on that each object will be string,string

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're looking for, but this question i think is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212521/typescript-static-classes

Comment: You should give a example of your array result!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like you have not an array, but an object with a variable set of properties all of the same type.  That can be described with a string [index signature](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html).

```
type AppErrorTemplateType = {
    [name: string]: {
        template: string,
        code: string
    }
};
```